# Dynamic sitemap by next-sitemap

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to add server-sitemap.xml to my next js App by next-sitemap,
I will be grateful if anyone can explain how can i add dynamic sitemap by next-sitemap in nextjs.

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next"
import { getServerSideSitemap,ISitemapField } from "next-sitemap"
const { all_product_get }  = require("../../src/api/guest")
export const  getServerSideProps =  GetServerSideProps async (ctx) => {
let data = [] 
await all_product_get().then(res => {
data : res.data.data
})
const fields :ISitemapField[]  = data.map(item => ({loc :`https://sivanland.com/product/detail/${item._id}`,
lastmod: new Date().toISOString()}))
return getServerSideSitemap(ctx, fields);
};
export default function Site(){}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what's not working?

Comment: Check out this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/74518512/11564766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself.

1. Add TypeScript to my project: `npm i -D typescript`
2. Add `tsconfig.json` to project root
3. Use TypeScript in NextJS.

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2017"
        ],
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "esnext",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "incremental": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "include": [
        "next-env.d.ts",
        "**/*.ts",
        "**/*.tsx"
    ]
}
```

4. Then I used the above code with dynamic data from the database:

```js
import { getServerSideSitemap, ISitemapField } from 'next-sitemap'
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next'

 export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
// Method to source urls from cms
const response = await fetch('https://newapi.example.com/api/guest/search   /product/all');
let items: any = {}
items = await response.json();

const fields: ISitemapField[] = items.data.map((item: any) => ({
    loc: `https://www.example.com/product/detail/${item._id}`,
    lastmod: new Date().toISOString(),
    changefreq: 'daily',
    priority: '0.7'
}));
return getServerSideSitemap(ctx, fields)
}

export default function Site() { }
```

5. Add folder: pages/server-sitemap.xml/index.tsx
6. and paste the above code to index.tsx
7. Add site map address to next-sitemap.gonfig.js

```js
additionalSitemaps: [
  'https://example.com/sitemap.xml',
  'https://example.com/server-sitemap.xml'
]
```